# Loading a jquery plugin page from a virtual directory in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm working on a small php project. therefore, I'm using ckeditor for better text editor, which is very simple installation, you just link its main javascript page and it will call rest of the dependencies.  Here is my code for editor.php and its dependencies are located in same folder.

```
<script src="ckeditor.js"></script>
<link href="content.css">
<textarea class="ckeditor" cols="5" rows="10" style="border-color:black;" name="editor1"></textarea>
```

Now my problem is, if I include this file (editor.php) from another location, it doesn't load its dependencies. How can I solve this problem?

thank in advance

Comment: Make the `src` of your JS file include a root-relative path (e.g. start it with "/"). Note: I use the term absolute path for cases where the domain is included in the path... I realise this may upset a few :)

Comment: Use absolute path instead of relative.

Comment: `<script src="/web/url/leading/to/ckeditor.js">`?

Answer (score 0):

Just use an absolute path:

This:

```
<script src="www.yourdomain.com/scripts/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

Instead of:

```
<script src="ckeditor.js"></script>
```